# VBA TAG RIBBON ACTIVATE on event

Tags: excel, vba, tags

I would like to enable custom tabs based on the activated sheets. So I have an event macro at the workbook level.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    tabActivate objRibbonDyn
End Sub
```

The ribbon was previously declared as an object during the ribbon onload procedure

I planned the following procedure to activate my ribbon tabs, but vba gives me an error: variable.. Type incompatibility

```
Sub tabActivate(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)

Select Case ActiveSheet.Name

    “Sheet1” box
        objDynRibbon.ActivateTab (“Custom Tab2”)
    “Sheet2” box
        objDynRibbon.ActivateTab (“Custom Tab3”)
    “Graph1” box
        objRibbonDyn.ActivateTab ("OngTB0l")
        
End Select

End Sub
```

I tried to obtain solutions with Bing AI (GPT4), but its knowledge is not yet at human level :-)

Thank you for a solution or possible solution.

Sincerely

Comment: The first thing to try is to change the curly quotes into normal quotes, and then also remove the parenthesis.

Comment: and use a valid `case` structure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a night of reflection, I think it is useless to pass a parameter to the procedure.

```
Sub tabActivate()

Select Case ActiveSheet.Name

     “Sheet1” box
         objDynRibbon.ActivateTab (“Custom Tab2”)
     “Sheet2” box
         objDynRibbon.ActivateTab (“Custom Tab3”)
     “Graph1” box
         objRibbonDyn.ActivateTab("OngTB0l")
        
End Select

End Sub
```

the parameter useful for activatetab is passed in the case occurrences...and i Try this afternoon and it s ok

Comment: What do you try accomplishing, in fact? To activate specific Ribbon tabs according to active sheet name? Then, do you want suggesting that your above code works as you need? Are the custom tabs designed by you (in XML, I mean)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to automate what (I understood) you try doing, please use the next approach:

1. The bases of automation should be a XML file of the next pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI onLoad="RibbonLoaded_MyAddin" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
  <ribbon> 
    <tabs> 
      <tab id="Custom Tab2" label="My New 2"  insertAfterMso="TabHome"> 
        <group id="Group1" label="myLabel"> 
           <!-- some controls here -->
        </group> 
      </tab>
      <tab id="Custom Tab3" label="My New Tab3"  insertAfterMso="TabHome"> 
        <group id="Group2" label="myLabe2"> 
           <!-- some controls here -->
        </group> 
      </tab>
      <tab id="OngTB0l" label="OngTB"  insertAfterMso="TabHome"> 
        <group id="Group3" label="myLabe3"> 
           <!-- some controls here -->
        </group> 
      </tab>      
    </tabs> 
  </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

`onLoad` event is triggered when `Ribbon` is loaded and it calls `RibbonLoaded_MyAddin` Sub.

2. Please, copy the next code in a standard module of the respective workbook:

```
Option Explicit


'To memorize Ribbon object pointer ___________
#If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
        Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If
'____________________________________________

Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI
Const strRib As String = "\MyRibb"

Sub RibbonLoaded_MyAddin(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Open Path For Output As #File
        Print #File, ObjPtr(ribbon) 'memorize IRibbonUI pointer
    Close #File

   Set myRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

Sub getRibbon() 'reSet myRibbon if it was lost (it's Nothing):
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Dim ribValue As String
    
    If myRibbon Is Nothing Then
        Open Path For Input As #File
            Input #File, ribValue
        Close #File
        
        #If VBA7 Then
            CopyMemory myRibbon, CLngPtr(ribValue), 8 'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer '64 bit
        #Else
            CopyMemory myRibbon, CLng(ribValue), 4    'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer
        #End If
    End If
End Sub
```

3. Copy the next event in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  If myRibbon Is Nothing Then getRibbon 'reset Ribbon object if it has been lost from memory
  
  Select Case Sh.Name
    Case "Sheet1"
        myRibbon.ActivateTab "Custom Tab2"
    Case "Sheet2"
        myRibbon.ActivateTab "Custom Tab3"
    Case "Graph1"
        myRibbon.ActivateTab "OngTB0l"
    Case Else
        myRibbon.ActivateTabMso "TabHome" 'activate Home tab
  End Select
End Sub
```

Now, activate different sheets and see how the Tabs activating sequence works.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

The code is not tested but I used this way (for something else) in many cases.

If something not clear, plese do not hesitate to ask for clarifications

Comment: @phmauber Didn't you still find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it do what you asked for?